# how to compare for equality for None objects in custom class in python?

Tags: python, class, object, comparison, equals

I am writing a `Queue` data structure for python purely for learning purposes. here is my `class`. when I compare two `Queue` object for equality, I get error. I think the error pops up, because I dont compare for `None` in my `__eq__` .but how can I check for `None` and `return` accordinly. in fact, I am using `list` under the hood and calling its `__eq__`, thinking it should take care as shown here, but it does not

```
>>> l=[1,2,3]
>>> l2=None
>>> l==l2
False
```

Here is my class:

```
@functools.total_ordering
class Queue(Abstractstruc,Iterator):

    def __init__(self,value=[],**kwargs):
        objecttype = kwargs.get("objecttype",object)
        self.container=[]
        self.__klass=objecttype().__class__.__name__
        self.concat(value)


    def add(self, data):
        if (data.__class__.__name__==self.__klass or self.__klass=="object"): 
            self.container.append(data)
        else:
            raise Exception("wrong type being added")

    def __add__(self,other):
        return Queue(self.container + other.container)


    def __iadd__(self,other):
        for i in other.container:
            self.add(i)
        return self


    def  remove(self):
        return self.container.pop(0)


    def peek(self):
        return self.container[0]


    def __getitem__(self,index):
        return self.container[index]


    def __iter__(self):
        return Iterator(self.container)

    def concat(self,value):
        for i in value:
            self.add(i)

    def __bool__(self):
        return len(self.container)>0

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.container)


    def __deepcopy__(self,memo):
        return Queue(copy.deepcopy(self.container,memo))

    def __lt__(self,other):
        return self.container.__lt__(other.container)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.container.__eq__(other.container)
```

But when I try compare using the above class I get:

```
>>> from queue import Queue
>>> q = Queue([1,2,3])
>>> q
>>> print q
<Queue: [1, 2, 3]>
>>> q1 = None
>>> q==q1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "queue.py", line 65, in __eq__
    return self.container.__eq__(other.container)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'container'
>>>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is how you are implementing `__eq__`.

Look at this code:

```
q = Queue([1,2,3])
q1 = None
q==q1
```

And lets rewrite it as the equivilent:

```
q = Queue([1,2,3])
q == None
```

Now, in `Queue.__eq__` we have:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    return self.container.__eq__(other.container)
```

But `other` is `None`, which means the return statement is calling:

```
self.container.__eq__(None.container)
```

As your error rightly states:

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'container'
```

Because it doesn't! `None` doesn't have a container attribute.

So, the way to do it, depends on how you want to treat it. Now, obviously, a `Queue` object can't be `None` if its been defined, so:

```
return other is not None and self.container.__eq__(other.container)
```

Will lazily evaluate if `other` is `None`, and return `False` before evalauting the part of the expression after the `and`. Otherwise, it will perform the evaulation. However, you will get other issues if `other` is not of type `Queue` (or more correctly the other object doesn't have a `container` attribute), such as:

```
q = Queue([1,2,3])
q == 1
>>> AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'container'
```

So... depending on your logic, and if a `Queue` can't be "equal" to other types *(which is something only you can say)*, you can check for the correct type like so:

```
return other is not None and type(self) == type(other) and self.container.__eq__(other.container)
```

But... `None` is a `NoneType`, so it can never be of the same type as a `Queue`. So we can shorten it again to just:

```
return type(self) == type(other) and self.container.__eq__(other.container)
```

edit: As per mglisons comments:

This could be made more pythonic by using the regular equality statement:

```
return type(self) == type(other) and self.container == other.container
```

They have also raised a good point regarding the use of `type` in checking eaulity. If you are certain that `Queue` would never be subclassed (which is difficult to state). You could use exception handling to capture the `AttributeError` effectively, like so:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    try:
        return self.container == other.container
    except AttributeError:
        return False    # There is no 'container' attribute, so can't be equal
    except:
        raise           # Another error occured, better pay it forward
```

The above may be considered a little overengineered, but is probably one of the better ways to approach this from a safety and resuability perspective.

Or a better, shorter approach (which I should have thought of initially) using `hasattr` is:

```
return hasattr(other, 'container') and self.container == other.container
```

Comment: Why do `self.container.__eq__(...)` when you can just do `self.container == ...`?  Also, I'm not sure about recommending the equality of `type`.  What about subclasses, etc?

Comment: @mgilson I was just reusing the OPs code. You could rewrite it as `self.container ==`. You've got me with the `type` checking though. What would you suggest instead?

Comment: @mgilson: i tried `self.container==other.container`, I still get the same error probably because of the same reason which `Lego `pointed out. `None` type has no attribute `container`

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr -- I suppose you could try `hasattr` to see if `other` has a `container` attribute and rely on duck-typing.

Comment: @mgilson: will `instanceof` not help instead of `hasattr`. I might have a `Stack` class with `container` attribute in it correct?

Comment: @mgilson I've added a longer approach addressing your good comments. This question recommends against type checking in general, so I've used exception handing as a way to handle that. Feel free to comment. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912972/python-how-do-i-check-in-runtime-if-a-given-class-is-a-subclass-of-another-gi

Comment: @user1988876 -- you mean `isinstance`?  Sure, you could try that.  e.g. `return isinstance(other, Queue) and self.container == other.container`

Comment: @user1988876 A lot of it depends on what you as the programmer think. If a `Queue` can only be equal to other `Queue`s, but never their subclasses, then `type(self) == type(other)` is valid. But thats up to you. There are a few approaches here, although the question I linked in the above comment recommends against `isinstance` and similar approaches.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr: Thanks for the discussion. The article you suggested above prefers duck typing which more of a try/except method correct? as shown here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17028722/is-this-duck-typing-in-python

Answer (score 3):

Tell Python that you don't know how to compare against other types:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    if not isinstance(other, Queue):
        return NotImplemented
    return self.container.__eq__(other.container)
```

you might consider checking `hasattr(other, 'container')` instead of the `isinstance`, or catch the `AttributeError`.

But the important thing is that, unlike other answers recommend, you *do not* want to `return False` when `other` isn't a Queue. If you return `NotImplemented`, Python will give `other` a chance to check the equality; if you return False, it won't. Differentiate between the *three* possible answers to the question "are these objects equal": yes, no, and I don't know.

You'll want to do something similar in your `__lt__`, where the difference is even more apparent: if you return `False` from both `__lt__` and `__eq__`, then the `__gt__` inserted by `total_ordering` will return True - even though you *can't do the comparison*. If you return `NotImplemented` from both of them, it will also be `NotImplemented`.

Comment: I didn't know about returning `NotImplemented`.  I thought maybe this was a mistake and you meant raising an exception... nope, no mistake: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/878943/why-return-notimplemented-instead-of-raising-notimplementederror

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like

```
    def __eq__(self,other):
        if other is None: return False
        return self.container.__eq__(other.container)
```

You may also want to do something like

```
if not isinstance(other,Queue): return False
```